# How to get document using lookup and search documents (inside of lookup) in nested array

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Hi i have 2 collections:
1) **"vehicle"** collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d793f20e340f375b4dcf67f"),
           ...some more fields that doesn't matter
}
```

2) **"companies"** collection (this collection has nested array of vehicles inside other array - **"companyBases"**):

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5d793f20e340f375b4dcf681"),

    "companyBases": [
        {
            "vehicles": [
                {

                    "_id": ObjectId("5d793f20e340f375b4dcf635"),
                      ...some more fields that doesn't matter
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
    ...some more fields that doesn't matter
}
```

I would like to execute lookup on **"vehicles"** collection, find document from **"companies"** collection based on **"_id"** nested in **"vehicles"** array (it's nested in **"companyBases"**) and match to **"_id"** of vehicle object.

I am working on **"vehicles"** collection makings some operations:

```
db.vehicles.aggregate([
  ...operations that doesn't matter (to this point everyting is working correctly - mongo displays me correct result)
  {
      $lookup: {
          from: "companies",
          let: {
            vehicleId: "$_id"
          },
          pipeline: [
              {
                  $unwind: "$companyBases"
              },
              {
                  $match: {
                      "companyBases.vehicles._id": "$$vehicleId"
                  }
              }

          ],
          as: "company"
      }
  }
]);
```

I've tried above code to resolve problem (and a lot of others with $elemMatch, $eq pipelines and others.....).

If i remove $match pipeline, $unwind operation is working correctly (but it displays me every docs from **"companies"** collection). I would like to get document from **"companies"** collection where vehicle object (**in "companyBases" array**) contains **"_id"** equeal to **"_id" in "vehicles"** collection.

## EDIT 1:

I don't get any error but objects are containg "company" field with empty object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct comparison won't work for the **$let** variables. These can only be used inside expressions. The following is the updated query:

```
db.vehicles.aggregate([
  ...operations that doesn't matter (to this point everything is working correctly - mongo displays me correct result)
  {
        $lookup:{
            "from":"companies",
            "let":{
                "vehicleId":"$_id"
            },
            "pipeline":[
                {
                    $unwind:"$companyBases"
                },
                {
                    $match:{
                        $expr:{
                            $in:["$$vehicleId","$companyBases.vehicles._id"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "as":"company"
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: does this kind of $lookup supported in mongo version 3.4, if not from what version it is supported?

Comment: ya, got my ans, version 3.6 it is.